# Performance Difference

Tags: performance

Suppose I write a code like this

```
if(i==100)

{
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

or I write a code like this

```
if(i==100) System.out.println("hello");
```

Will there be any difference in the performance and efficiency of above two codes?

Comment: Why would there be any difference at all? It's possible (and even likely) that the stages of the compiler after the front-end won't even be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no difference in performance, only readability is less if you leave the brackets out. Also because you need to know that only the first line after your condition will be executed.